# index.html:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: createParagraph is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:35:39)

Tags: javascript, html

Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: createParagraph is not defined
at onclick (c:\WorkSpace\Introduction to JavaScript\Introduction to JavaScript\index.html:35:39)
onclick @ c:\WorkSpace\Introduction to JavaScript\Introduction to JavaScript\index.html:35:39

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript Beast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoader', () => {

            function createParagraph() {
                const para = document.createElement('p');
                para.textContent = 'You clicked to create Paragraph';
                document.body.appendChild(para);
            }
            //Here this event is added inside the button
            const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

            for (const button of buttons) {
                button.addEventListener('click',createParagraph);
            }
        });
    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>JavaScript Internal</h1>
    <!--the button function is tagged to this <button></button>-->
    <button onclick="createParagraph"> Click here to create a Paragraph</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Not sure why the onlick -"createParagraph" is not defined?

I tried to check if there was any misspellings, but everything seemed to be fine to me. This html file was done through a tutorial guide. So I'm not sure how there was a mistake on my part.

Comment: I'm surprised that code is even running, considering the event is named `DOMContentLoaded`, not `DOMContentLoader`... Also, it will work if you remove the `onclick="createParagraph"` from the HTML. You're adding the event listener in JavaScript, you don't need to also do it in HTML.

Comment: Because `DOMContentLoader` is not a thing, so your anonymous function inside of which `createParagraph`would get defined, never executes. It's `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: @HereticMonkey _"I'm surprised that code is even running"_ - it isn't, the `onclick` attribute on the button itself assigned the callback here - and that then doesn't find the function, because the "DOMContentLoader" callback never executed. The `for (const button of buttons) { button.addEventListener('click',createParagraph); }` never executed in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Yay, you finally found something to nitpick about my comment that rings true. Congratulations! :-P

Comment: @HereticMonkey I wasn't trying to nit-pick, just to give an explanation - if perhaps not for your benefit, then at least for other people reading along.

Comment: Another issue potentially is the declaration of `createParagraph` within the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler itself - this makes it inaccessible/undefined to statically added HTML elements such as the button. Having both the inline and externally registered event handlers will, if the `createParagraph` function is declared outside the `DOMContentLoaded` handler, invoke that function twice so remove inline `onclick` calls whenever possible.